# Any way I can send SMS?

Tags: c#, .net, sms, alert

How can I make my application send SMS using C#? My current configuration sends E-mail alerts but SMS alerts are better suited for my purpose. Any way I can do that for free/paid?

Comment: This is not really a C# question. you have to find a service provider and they will probably have an API you can use.

Comment: Sending SMS's varies widely depending on the country from and to which you are sending (e.g. some countries charge to send SMS's, others charge to receive SMS's). Many SP's have a free email to SMS gateway, e.g. SomeCellNumber@somesp.com, although these are usually limited to a few sms's per day.

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3043301/service-for-sending-sms-and-making-voice-calls-from-web-site-and-desktop-applicat

Comment: I didn't claim it is a C# question... I'm using C# so I tagged it C#.. it is a general question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need an SMS provider.  One such provider is [clickatell.com](http://www.clickatell.com) who I have bought in bulk from before.  They have a good service, and an extensive API.  You have to pay for the SMS, but like everything in life, the better quality stuff costs more.  I've found them reliable and their phone support is good.

There are a few free ones out there, but they are obviously going to be heavily restricted and finding one that allows use for commercial products would be hard to find.  You also have to be careful with user data, free ones may auto sign your numbers on for marketting etc, so make sure your users are aware of that if that's the route you wish to take.

Just a disclaimer that I have no affiliation with Clickatell, and there are lots more options out there, but beware of resellers who provide sub par service at inflated prices.

Answer (score 2):

Second vote for [ClickATell](http://www.clickatell.com) for fast, flexible, simultaneous SMS delivery (and full tracking of SMS message delivery status).

An alternative is that you could use a USB/serial GSM modem ([WaveCom](http://www.sms-integration.com/p_32-wavecom-fastrack-sms.html)) or cell phone and send SMS's via the venerable 'AT' command set. For serial-based SMS, there are quite a few .NET component sets, to make it easier. One such component set is [TOxygenSMS](http://www.oxygensoftware.com/en/products/tsms/). Going the serial route means each SMS takes about 5 seconds and must be sent in series.

I have used both with great success. Use a SMS gateway if you have Internet access and a GSM modem in other cases.

Answer (score 1):

We have been using [Essendex](http://www.esendex.co.uk/) for a while now and it works well and pretty reliable.

Answer (score 1):

without a [SMS sending gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SMS_gateway) it is not possible. you need a services provider who provide you a services to sending sms see here a aticle 
http://www.developershome.com/sms/howToChooseSMSGateway.asp

Answer (score 1):

If this is for a small application the you don't need to pay for a gateway. Assuming that you know the provider, you can just use this [list of SMS transit providers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_carriers_providing_SMS_transit). For the most part, the big players offer it but they may have some limitations for number of texts per day. It works very well - you just have to send an email to: 1234567890@sms.provider.com.

Answer (score 1):

I have [written a C# library for Twilio](http://github.com/johnsheehan/TwilioApi) that lets you send SMS in two lines of code.

Note that while I now work at Twilio, I released this library prior to working here.

Answer (score 0):

A free option to get text message alerts is actually just create an account on [www.totxt.com](http://www.totxt.com) and you can just send an email to USER_NAME@totxt.com and receive it via SMS. This is better for alerts for a small group then for bulk SMS.

Answer (score 0):

alternative to SMS Gateway is using a Modem maybe a phone or a GSM Modem and study of AT Commands.

you can use .net SerialPort Class